# How to get parent name and name in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
//Table model
    id  parent name
    1     0     Nokia
    2     0     Samsung
    3     1     N70
    4     1     N97
    5     2     Galaxy S3

//Table image
    id    name
    1    n70.png
    2    n97.png
    3    galaxys3_1.png
    4    galaxys3_2.png
    5    galaxys3_3.png

//Table image_to_model
   id    model_id   image_id
    1        3       1
    2        4       2
    3        2       3
    4        2       4
    5        2       5

SELECT mod.id, mod.name,GROUP_CONCAT(img.name) FROM `model` AS mod
LEFT JOIN `image_to_model` AS mod_img ON mod_img.image_id = mod.id
GROUP BY mod.id
```

How to result in this format:

```
1 Nokia   | N70,N97  |  n70.png,n97.png
2 Samsung |Galaxy S3 | galaxys3_1.png,galaxys3_2.png,galaxys3_3.png
```

Comment: Can you post a dump of phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend splitting the brands (Nokia, Samsung, etc.) out into their own table.  Then you would just join from the models table to the brands table via a brand_id.